# Linux Mint 19.1 "Could not download all repository indexes"

Tags: linux-mint

I upgraded my Linux Mint from 19 to 19.1 and tried to refresh the package information. Here is the message I got. What do I need to do here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean re-installation of Linux Mint 19.1. The problems are gone now. It must be some compatibility issue with previous versions.